# Understanding how to use post- condition and loop-invariant correctly with Frama-c

Tags: functional-testing, frama-c

I am trying to prove on this example that the return value will be either 0(if 8  is not in array) or 1(if 8 in array).

---

```
int fi8(int *array, int size) {
  int fi8 = 0;
  int i = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < length; ++i)
  {
     if(array[i] == 8)
     fi8 = 1;
  }
  return fi8;
}
```

And I created pre- and post conditions:

```
/*@ requires 0 <= size <= 100;
@  requires  \valid(array+(0..size-1));
@  assigns \nothing;
@  ensures (\forall integer i; 0<= i < size && array[i] != 8)  ==> (\result == 0);
@  ensures (\exists integer i; (0<= i < size && array[i] == 8)) && (\result == 1);
@*/
```

and loop invariants, because Frama-C is based on Hoare Logic:

```
/*@ loop invariant 0 <= i <= length;
  @  loop invariant  fi8 == 0 || fi8 == 1;
  @  loop invariant (\forall integer i; 0<= i < size && array[i] != 8)
      ==> (fi8 == 0);
  @  loop invariant (\exists integer i; (0<= i < size && array[i] == 8)) 
      && (fi8 == 1);
  @  loop assigns i, fi8;
  @*/
```

I'm pretty sure that I'm missing something on the lines, where I'm trying to use forall
and exists.
I spend hours trying to understand, how can I check correctly, if any value is assigned on array or not, but I feel like I'm stuck here.
I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Frama-C is not based on Hoare logic, although some Frama-C plug-ins may be.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few issues with your code. First, you seem to have mixed `size` and `length`. I've taken the liberty to use `size` everywhere, otherwise this code won't even be accepted by a C compiler, let alone by Frama-C. Second, `\forall integer i; 0<= i < size && array[i] != 8` (and the corresponding loop invariant) is incorrect. Literally, it means that any integer `i` verifies **both** that `i` is between `0` **and** `size` and `array[i]` is not `8`. Taking `101` for `i` gives a trivial counter-example to this proposition. What you want to express is that for any integer `i`, **if** `i` is between `0` and `size`, **then** `array[i]` is not `8`, which is expressed as `\forall integer i; 0<= i < size ==> array[i] != 8`. On the other hand, the `&&` connector is correct when used under the `\exists`: this time we indeed want to find an `i` such that `i` is within the bounds of the array and for which `array[i]==8`. However, the second `&&` in your last ensures is not correct: what you want to say is that **if** there is such an `i`, then `\result == 1`, hence you must have an implication here: `(\exists integer i; 0<= i < size && array[i] == 8) ==> (fi8 == 1)`

The last issue is with your loop invariants. You are re-using as a quantified variable while it is already a C variable, which is often not a good idea. In fact, it is a real problem, since the property you want to express is that as long as we have not seen an `8` between `0` and `i`, `fi8==0` (and dually that if if have seen an `8`, `fi8==1`), `i` being the C variable. If you use `j` in your quantification, as in

```
 loop invariant (\forall integer j; 0<= j < i ==> array[j] != 8) ==> (fi8 == 0);
 loop invariant (\exists integer j; 0<= j < i && array[j] == 8) ==> (fi8 == 1);
```

all proof obligations are discharged.